# question about counting digits

Tags: combinatorics

If I have a 12 digit string of ones and zeros, how many different 12 digit strings can I create from it?

Is that similar to using 12!   ?

Comment: Could you please explain your thought process for solving this problem?

Comment: I do not understand your question completely.  "*how many different 12 digit strings can I create* **from it**"  In what way are you creating strings **from** the "12 digit string of ones and zeroes" that you have?  Supposing you "have" the string `111100000000`, are you asking how many rearrangements of this there are?  In other words, asking how many 12-digit strings there are with exactly four 1's and eight 0's?  That would be $\binom{12}{4}$.  Do you recognize the answer changes based on what the first string you started with was?

Comment: Or are you perhaps asking how many 12-digit strings there are with 0's and/or 1's, counting all the strings from `000000000000, 000000000001, 000000000010, ..., 111111111110, 111111111111`?  For this, it is a simple matter of rule of product.  $2$ choices for the first digit, $2$ choices for the second, etc... multiplying the number of choices for each step together to get the total.  Similarly, you could just interpret the strings as binary numbers and see that every binary number from $0_2$ to $111111111111_2$ is present exactly once each.

Comment: This has nothing to do with factorials.  Don't try to shoehorn factorials into problems where they don't belong.  The only thing that it has to do with factorials is that it is a counting problem and this and factorials both rely on the same underlying basic principles of counting, specifically the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Each digit can either be $1$ or $0$. This gives $2$ choices for each digit.

Since there are $12$ digits, the total number of ways is $2*2*2...*2$ where there are $12$ $2$'s since each digit is an independent event. So this gives $2^{12} = 4096$ total ways.

b) It's not similar to using $12!$ since that would be a lot more $2$'s. Specifically, the total number of ways would be $2^{12!}$ which would be huge.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Thank you

Comment: @CacklingMuse no problem :)